# How to plot truncated distributions (truncdist) with fitdistrplus?

Tags: r, truncate, data-fitting, truncation, fitdistrplus

I am attempting to plot goodness of fit curves to truncated distributions from the fitdistrplus package using its plot function.

```
library(fitdistrplus)
library(truncdist)
library(truncnorm)
dataNum <- c(433.6668, 413.0450, 435.9952, 449.7559, 457.3629, 498.6187, 598.0335, 637.5611, 644.9193, 634.4843, 620.8676, 590.6622, 581.6411, 572.5022, 594.0925, 587.7293, 608.4948, 626.7594, 599.0286, 611.2966, 572.1749, 545.0071, 490.0298, 478.8484, 458.8293, 437.4878, 467.7026, 477.4094, 467.4182, 519.3056, 599.0155, 648.8603, 623.0672, 606.3737, 552.3653, 558.7612, 553.1345, 549.5961, 546.0578, 565.4582, 562.6825, 606.6225, 578.1584, 572.6201, 546.4735, 514.8147, 479.4638, 462.7702, 430.3652, 452.9671)
```

If I use the library(truncnorm) to fit a truncated normal distribution, everything works fine.

```
fit.dataNormTrunc2 <- fitdist(dataNum, "truncnorm", fix.arg=list(a=min(dataNum)), start = list(mean = mean(dataNum), sd = sd(dataNum)))
plot(fit.dataNormTrunc2)
```

However, if I try to use the truncdist package, only the histogram comparison plot prints without any of the other plots (e.g. qq-plot). I also get an error:

```
Error in qtNorm(p = c(0.01, 0.03, 0.05, 0.07, 0.09, 0.11, 0.13, 0.15,  : 
unused argument (p = c(0.01, 0.03, 0.05, 0.07, 0.09, 0.11, 0.13, 0.15, 0.17, 0.19, 0.21, 0.23, 0.25, 0.27, 0.29, 0.31, 0.33, 0.35, 0.37, 0.39, 0.41, 0.43, 0.45, 0.47, 0.49, 0.51, 0.53, 0.55, 0.57, 0.59, 0.61, 0.63, 0.65, 0.67, 0.69, 0.71, 0.73, 0.75, 0.77, 0.79, 0.81, 0.83, 0.85, 0.87, 0.89, 0.91, 0.93, 0.95, 0.97, 0.99))
```

The code used is:

```
dtNorm <- function(x, mean, sd) {
    dtrunc(x, "norm", mean, sd, a=min(dataNum), b=Inf)
}
ptNorm <- function(x, mean, sd) {
    ptrunc(x, "norm", mean, sd, a=min(dataNum), b=Inf)
}
qtNorm <- function(x, mean, sd) {
    qtrunc(x, "norm", mean, sd, a=min(dataNum), b=Inf)
}
fit.dataNormTrunc <- fitdist(dataNum, "tNorm", start = c(mean=mean(dataNum), sd=sd(dataNum)))
plot(fit.dataNormTrunc)
```

I have also tried the truncdist approach with the lognormal functionand again the other 3 plots don't print out and I get the same error about the values not being used.

Comment: the error indicates that you should rename the parameter `x` of your function `qtNorm` to `p` .